# Getting data from mssql to Eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

my first time in eclipse and im trying to get some test data from my sql server,now the problem is i have setup a sql connection using ms jdbc drivers and it seems like it works but when i run my query from eclipse,i get

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
>   'KategoriName'.

error.My query works fine in sql manager.What could be the problem?I'm adding the code below as well:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.155;user=user;password=password";


Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs;

                String sqlconn="select [KategoriName] from [FINSAT6G9].[TBL_Test] whereID=493";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlconn);

String aa = rs.getString("KategoriName");


System.out.println(aa);
```

Cheers.

Comment: maybe a typo, but you're missing a space after the 'where'

Comment: sorry a typo there,but it is not the cause of the problem unfortunately..

Comment: So if you run `select [KategoriName] from [FINSAT6G9].[TBL_Test] whereID=493` from SSMS you get results, but when you run it from code you get invalid column name? Are you sure that you're connecting to the right server? If so, what is the default catalog (database) for the user you're logging in as? Is it possible it's a different database than the one you're wanting to connect to? If that other database has a `TBL_Test` table in the `FINSAT6G9` schema and doesn't have the `KategoriName` column on it, then that would explain the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the database name in the connection string as so:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.155;user=user;password=password;databaseName=FINSAT6G9";
```

Because, obviously, the error is telling you that the `KategoriName` column doesn't exist which can only mean 2 things: You have a typo or you are attempting to get the data from the wrong place, either the wrong database or the wrong table.

Comment: Nope,adding databasename didnt work either,better contact my system admin :/